# Creating word wrap of variable length using hasNext in Java

Tags: java, file, iterator, stringbuilder

I'm trying to create code that will accept input from a file, and wrap it to a variable column width. It uses whitespace as a delimiter and, when the word would cause the line length to exceed the column width, output the words in the string to file, and start a new line. There is a logic error in my loop, and only 2 words are printed per line, and the second word in a line becomes the first word in the subsequent line. Here's my code so far:

```
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {          
        String word = (reader.next() + " ");            
        int length = line.length();         
        if (length <= width)                
        line.append(word);
        outputStream.println(line);
        line.delete(0, length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: Every word(including " ") in the input has a length less than or equal to the mentioned column width

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
while (reader.hasNext()) {          
    String word = (reader.next() + " ");            
    int length = line.length() + word.length();         
    if (length <= width) {               
    line.append(word);
    continue;
    } 
    outputStream.println(line);
    line.setLength(0)
    line.append(word);
}
if(line.length() > 0){
outputStream.print(line);
}
```

Comment: It's true - supercalifragilisticexpialidocious would throw an exception. 
Working now - thanks so much for the help!